# How to insert events into Google Calendar from server with client token

Tags: android, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I need to insert events to a Google Calendar account from a Python server, but the flow of my application is:

- The user downloads and installs the android app
- The user selects a Google account
- A token is generated in the android app
- The token is sent over https to the server
- The server, after some processing, insert a new event to Google Calendar through the token received

The questions are:

1. Will this flow work?
2. What libraries do I need to use on server and android app? I've read the official documentation, but I'm confused about what should I use.
3. Do I need to know something else?

At this moment, I can login in the android app, but I don't know how to get the desired permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to get a refresh token too in case your server is done processing after the Oauth token has expired. There is a Calendar Python client library that you can use on the server (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/downloads) and there is a Java client library you should be able to use on the client (https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp#libraries).